# Performing MatchableHandlerMapping lookup. it is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/hello' (previous null). Performing MatchableHandlerMapping lookup. it is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.

```
package com.springsec.springsecurityclient.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
            "/hello",
            "/register"
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS).permitAll();


        return http.build();
```

[I need to have the localhost like this (PS : DAILY CODE BUFFER YT SPRING BOOT INDEPTH COURSE TIMESTAMP = 41:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L87GZ.png)

[I am getting as "ACCESS TO LOCALHOST DENIED"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6F5.png)

My spring boot version is 3.2.0 so I adjusted all the dependencies version below or same as that
This my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springsec</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring security</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version> <!-- You can adjust the version based on your requirements -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME WITH THIS....

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you are watching is outdated in my opinion.
Here you have some to do more changes to get a working version of project.

1.About Security Layer, you have to read/check [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) & [Use the Lambda DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html) and after it will have next one `WebSecurityConfig`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
      "/hello",
      "/register"
  };

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
      request.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS).permitAll();
      request.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

2.Second one is to remove all `javax.x` imports of dependency from project and also replace it to `jakarta.x` because since from `spring-boot` `3.x` all `javax` imports were replaced by `jakarta.x` More details you could find here [preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0).

3.About `pom.xml` you have to change it something like next one.
`dependencies` part:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    

  </dependencies>
```

And also my advice for future: Try to learn from documentation it is the best way to understand how a framework work.

Comment: But I am getting "Cannot resolve method cors in HttpSecurity" when i used your above code and also changing the pom.xml

Comment: package com.springsec.springsecurityclient.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain; FIle : enablewebSecurity

Comment: package com.springsec.springsecurityclient.controller;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  File : RegistrationController

Comment: import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;              File : User

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;      File : VerificationToken

Comment: import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import java.util.UUID;    File : EventListener

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;    FIle : CompleteEvent

import com.springsec.springsecurityclient.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;   File : userRepo

Comment: please update the question with current error message.

Comment: import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;   class : tokenRepository

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;  class springsecurityApplication